# No group of following property. Is this true?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, p-groups

Let $p$ be a prime greater than 3 and $G$ be group of order $p^5$. Is it true that there is no group $G$ of order $p^5$ such that the order of frattini subgroup is $p^3$ and the order of center is $p^2$?

If the answer is yes, how to prove it.

Comment: One possible thing that might be useful: If $G/Z(G)$ is abelian, then $[G,G]\leq Z(G)$. So, using the well-known formula $(xy)^n=x^ny^n[y,x]^{n(n-1)/2}$ whenever $x$ and $y$ commute with $[x,y]$, we get that $(xy)^{p^3}=x^{p^3}y^{p^3}$. I.e., $x\mapsto x^{p^3}$ is a homomorphism. Moreover, since $Z(G)$ has order $p^2$, it follows that $x\mapsto x^{p^3}$ is a homomorphism to $Z(G)$.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The class $3$ quotient of the Burnside group $B(2,p)$ has these properties. It has the presentation

$\langle a,b,c,d,e \mid a^p=b^p=c^p=d^p=e^p=1, [b,a]=c, [c,a]=d, [c,b]=e, d,e\ {\rm central}\ \rangle$

The Frattini subgroup is $\langle c,d,e \rangle$ and the centre is $\langle d,e\rangle$.

Answer (score 0):

The Frattini subgroup is always characteristic, so if it's Abelian, then it must be central, which is a contradiction of the orders.  So the Frattini subgroup is not Abelian:  Apply Lemma 4 from http://msp.org/pjm/1960/10-1/pjm-v10-n1-p12-s.pdf

Comment: how one concludes that if Frattini subgroup is abelian, then it is central.

Comment: @Steve  Let $x$ be an element in a characteristic Abelian subgroup $H$ of a group $G$, and let $g\in G$ be any group element.  Then $g^{-1}xg\in H$ since $H$ is characteristic (in particular it is invariant under the inner-automorphism defined by $g$, but $g^{-1}xg=xg^{-1}g=x$ in $H$, since $H$ is Abelian.  So, $g^{-1}xg=x$ for all $g\in G$, this makes $x$ an element of the center.

Comment: @Gaffeny I do not understand how $g^{-1}xg=xg^{-1}x$. As $g \in G$ is arbitrary and $x \in H$. Why should $g^{-1}$ commute with $x$?

Comment: It's not true. For example the dihedral group of order 16 has abelian but not central Frattini subgroup.